# All window variables in one global namespace

Tags: javascript

I have a lot window variables in my project, some of them are just values, some of them are functions, whats the best practice for creating one global namespace for all of them, anf how should i use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Namespaces and global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475078/namespaces-and-global-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/9475093/1437016

Comment: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve this, best practice would be using a module system like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1). Alternatively you could follow the [generic module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). The way you use modules may be different for your environment, node.js for example uses the CommonJS module format, and NPM for package (module) management. In the browser its much more flexible, usually it comes down to including the appropriate script tags in your HTML document.